# Dynamic widgets in shiny

Tags: shiny

I have a sample application as below. The idea is only 2 widgets are seen by default. But when you click on "Add", the widgets keep on adding. But when we click "Add" for the first time, the widgets pops up (that is fine) and now when enter some value in "First Company" and then click on "Add", another widgets pops up(this is also fine). But now, the values in "First Company" disappears. Can we make is appear when we click on "Add"

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("fcompany"),
  uiOutput("add_exp"),
  actionButton("add_button", "Add")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  get_data <- reactiveValues()
  
  get_data$all_experiences <- c(0) 
  
  output$fcompany <- renderUI({
    column(width = 2, textInput("id_zero", label = "Gra", placeholder = "Col"), 
           numericInput("idexp_zero", label = "", value = 4, min = 0, max = 10))
  })
  
  
  observeEvent(input$add_button,{
    
    added_varaible <- max(get_data$all_experiences)+1
    
    excel_Input <- structure(list(number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), words = c("one", 
                                                                                       "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", 
                                                                                       "ten"), company = c("First Company", "Second Company", "Third Company", 
                                                                                                           "Fourth Company", "Fifth Company", "Sixth Company", "Seventh Company", 
                                                                                                           "Eighth Company", "Ninth Company", "Tenth Company")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                               10L), class = "data.frame")
    output$add_exp <- renderUI({
      lapply(1:added_varaible, function(i){
        column(width = 2, textInput(paste0("id_",excel_Input$words[excel_Input$number == i]), label = excel_Input$company[excel_Input$number == i], 
                                    placeholder = paste0("Enter the ", excel_Input$company[excel_Input$number == i])), 
               numericInput(paste0("idexp_",excel_Input$words[excel_Input$number == i]), label = "", value = 4, min = 0, max = 10))
      })
    })
    
    get_data$all_experiences <- c(get_data$all_experiences, added_varaible)
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not provide much context about the broader objective of the app.
I propose to pre-define all needed extension inputs and hide them by default. Later we can unhide each if needed.

```r
library(shiny)

excel_Input <- structure(
  list(
    number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
    words = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "ten"),
    company = c(
      "First Company", "Second Company", "Third Company",
      "Fourth Company", "Fifth Company", "Sixth Company", "Seventh Company",
      "Eighth Company", "Ninth Company", "Tenth Company"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, 10L),
  class = "data.frame"
)

ex_inputs <- append(
  list(shiny::tags$div(
    shiny::textInput("id_zero", label = "Gra", placeholder = "Col"),
    shiny::numericInput("idexp_zero", label = "", value = 4, min = 0, max = 10)
  )),
  lapply(
    seq_len(nrow(excel_Input)),
    function(i) {
      ex_word <- excel_Input$words[excel_Input$number == i]
      ex_label <- excel_Input$company[excel_Input$number == i]
      ex_company <- excel_Input$company[excel_Input$number == i]
      shiny::tags$div(
        id = sprintf("ex_%s", i),
        class = "hidden",
        shiny::textInput(
          paste0("id_", ex_word),
          label = ex_label,
          placeholder = paste0("Enter the ", ex_company)
        ),
        shiny::numericInput(paste0("idexp_", ex_word), label = ex_word, value = 4, min = 0, max = 10)
      )
    }
  )
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  shiny::tags$div(
    shiny::tags$div(
      style = "display: flex",
      ex_inputs
    ),
    shiny::tags$div(
      actionButton("add_button", "Add")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  counter <- shiny::reactiveVal(0)
  shiny::observeEvent(input$add_button, {
    if (counter() < 10) counter(counter() + 1)
  })
  shiny::observe(shinyjs::removeClass(sprintf("ex_%s", counter()), "hidden"))
  
  # Test
  observe({
    lapply(seq_len(counter()), function(i) {
      ex_word <- excel_Input$words[excel_Input$number == i]
      print(input[[paste0("id_", ex_word)]])
    })
  })
}

shiny::shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks. This helps. But what is wrong in my application? Can you alter that code if possible

Comment: Your application is rendering the UI for inputs from scratch each time a new input is added. So You lose the data from inputs. Your app was wrongly designed.

Comment: Hi Polkas, i got your code. But can you explain me what is ````shinyjs::removeClass(sprintf("ex_%s", counter()), "hidden")```` doing?

Comment: I will be happy to help. So by default, all inputs are available in the presented solution. However, we do not want to show all of them to the end-user when the app is initialized. So we add the hidden class to all additional inputs. Later we can remove the "hidden" class  (with `shinyjs::removeClass`) for each specific input and make it visible to the end user.

Comment: So you mean when I comment that line ````removeClass````, all inputs should be available right when app is initiated? But it does not happen